# How to get a list with all two-way bindings in WPF project

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, resharper

I'm maintaining a large WPF project targeted to .NET 4.5. It has to be migrated to .NET 4.5.2.

One of the changes in .NET 4.5.1 is that properties with private setters are no more allowed for two-way binding. But there are *a lot* of such properties in my project, some of them are two-way bound to views.

So after re-compiling the project with new target version and running the app a lot of views throw exceptions because of this new restriction.

Replacing `{ get; private set; }` by `{ get; set; }` in the whole project, of course, solves the problem, but I don't want to make it possible to set all properties from outside the viewmodel, it breaks the encapsulation principle. I would like to do this only with those properties that participate in two-way binding.

So **is there a way to get a list of *all* two-way bindings in a project in Visual Studio with Resharper?**
It would be even better if one could get only those two-way bindings which are bound to properies with private setters.

Just searching `Mode=TwoWay` in the whole project is NOT exhaustive because some bindings are two-way by default. But searching `Binding` will give too much unwanted results.

If it is not possible by using VS and R#, will writing custom VS extension help? How much difficult is it?

Comment: i was using Resharper from last couple of years , but did not came across such facility provided by R#.  I would do it manually. its more easy if you have MVVM. so that i would replace { get; private set; } by { get; set; } in Model Folder specifically. and before replacing i would right click on every property and go 'find uses' . then i would open the view folder only from search result, just to confirm its TwoWayBinding. and then i would replace it else skip it.

Comment: @Lina I would do it manually too if only there were not too many such properties in the project, it's very hard to check them all by hand, that's why I asked this question. The workaround I used is to visit all views in the application and, if `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, see its details that usually (not always, e.g. if incorrect binding is located in style) refer to the incorrect property location in sources. But it requires some time too and doesn't guarantee all properties will be found..

Comment: there should be plug in avaialble by microsoft while migrating one version to other... I was  searching for that, but couldnt find any.